# prolog implement custom flatten

Tags: prolog

Hello I have a list of list in prolog and I want to flatten them. I've made a preidacate that flatten lists as I wanted but I have this case:

`[[2,2,3],[3,2]]` to be flattened like this: `[2,2,3,0,3,2]`
*i.e.*, I want to add a 0 to the new list if the last element of the previous list is the same as the first element of the next list. Can you help me?

here is my work so far:

```
myflat([],[]) :- !.
myflat([H|T],Z) :- myflat(H,K), myflat(T,L), append(K,L,Z),!.
myflat(H,[H]) :- not(H = [K]).
```

but I cannot think how to check the equality of elements stated above

Comment: What do you expec for `myflat(a,X)`?

Comment: @false What do you mean? a is not variable, so not a list. So this would return false.Right?

Comment: Right, but your program is different here.

Comment: @false I just tested it. ?-myflat(a,X). -> false. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: `H = [K]` is true if `H` is a list of one element. It's unclear what your `myflat(H, [H])` is trying to say as a rule.

Comment: @lurker I considered it a base case not to be taken.. yes it's not good but it doesn't affect directly my quesion.

Comment: You definitely have not tested with above definition which succeeds with `X = [a]`!!

Comment: Worse: `myflat([], [[]])` succeeds as well...

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but works:

```
myflat([[A,B|List]|ListOfLists], [A|Output]) :-
    myflat([[B|List]|ListOfLists], Output).
myflat([[A],[A|List]|ListOfLists], [A,0|Output]) :-
    myflat([[A|List]|ListOfLists], Output).
myflat([[A],[B|List]|ListOfLists], [A|Output]) :-
    A =\= B,
    myflat([[B|List]|ListOfLists], Output).
myflat([[A]], [A]).
```

Sample input/output:

```
?- myflat([[1,2,1],[1,2],[2,1]], X).
X = [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1] .

?- myflat([[2,2,3],[3,2]],X).
X = [2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2] ;
false.
```